# how to create a custom formItem composed of 2 buttons and a table in smartgwt?

Tags: smartgwt

I want to create a formItem composed of 2 buttons (addButton, removeButton) and a table, the addButton adds a line to the table and the removeButtons removes the selected line.

Please Help.

Comment: Currently, I have a SelectItem which i derived into a MyCollectionItem and added 2 FormItemIcon to it with click handler for each Icon

Comment: You will find that it is much easier for others to help you if you include actual code in your questions. Please edit your question to include the relevant code that you have tried.

Comment: The code is confidential. Sorry.

Comment: In that case, you may want to construct a simple example that is similar to the production code, but omits any sensitive details. Here at Stack Overflow, as is typically the case in Internet help forums, the burden is on you to ask a question that can be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest when you want something special in a dynamicForm is to use the CanvasItem which allow you to "wrap" anything you like inside a formitem uniform.
So in your case you can put a Layout (H or V) with the members you likeIButton, GridList, Label .... and set the Canvas of your CanvasItem to this Layout (setCanvas()  method).

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. Just one more thing, does Validation of input also work in canvas item?

Comment: You have to try and look at [link](http://forums.smartclient.com/showthread.php?t=11651). In my case I just use CanvasItem to organize some buttons so I have no experience about validation issues.